# Declaring a dispatch_queue for use in more than one method

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to get my head around GCD and dispatch queues. I know that within a method I can declare a queue like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blah.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

However I also want to be able to access this queue from difference methods in the class. Can I just declare it as a property? i.e:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;
```

then in my init method use:

```
self.serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blah.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and when adding to the queue:

```
dispatch_async(self.serialQueue, ^{
    //block1
});
```

Is this okay to do or poor practice?

Comment: That's fine. Did you try it?

Comment: yes it works thanks, can I do UI work in these blocks? i.e. I want to queue [self.tableView reload] to happen after some other code completes

Comment: UI code must be done on the main thread.

Comment: I need to queue deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: and [self.tableView reload]. Is it possible to create a main thread queue for this?

Comment: `dispatch_get_main_queue`.

Comment: Don't use property setters/getters (on self) in `-init` or `-dealloc`. See also: http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/